# multiple resizables acting strange

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to place multiple resizable and draggable div's on one page that move (vertically) inside their own parent div.
you can take a look at http://bit.ly/bCutBE

However, these div's act really strange when I want to resize them, especially from the north side, they kind of move out of the screen very fast, while they shouldn't be able to get outside the parent div.
I only want the div to be able to move and resize vertically inside it's parent, the dragging-part works pretty good, but the resize part give this problem.

I can't really describe it better than this, but take a look for yourself and it will be clear immediately when you try to resize one of the coloured div's: move it a little downwards and try to resize it from the north side.

the problem seems to be caused by the containment: 'parent', line of the resizable. when I delete this line it works fine, but then the coloured blocks don't stay in their parent, and I want them to stay inside their parent.

I hope someone can help me with this...

the jquery code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".move")
                .draggable({
                    containment: 'parent', 
                    grid: [50,50],
                    axis: 'y'
                })
                .resizable({
                    containment: 'parent', 
                    grid: [50,50],
                    handles: 'n, s', 
                    minHeight: 50 
                });
        });
```

Comment: are trying to constraint the resize so that it can't be resized larger then the orginal size is that why you have containment in resizing  ?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a bug with draggable and sortable  you will find a [workaround here](http://aleembawany.com/2009/01/25/jquery-resizable-draggable-bug-workaround/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really understand how to adapt my code so that it's working, I'm quite new to jQuery you see...

could you help me a little further and tell me how to adapt my code?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not having any luck either